# Remove invalid row to add foreign key constraint?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables A and B.

B have ID_A column that "references" ID column of A, but without foreign key constraint (so no cascade deletion).

I want to add foreign key constraint to ID_A column, but there are some rows that have invalid value (due to deleted row of A).

Is there a way to remove this invalid rows?

Comment: "Is there a way to remove this invalid rows?" - Yes - but what about that are you stuck on? Have you consulted the documentation on `delete`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `LEFT JOIN` antipattern to identify and delete orphan records:

```
DELETE tb
FROM tableb tb
LEFT JOIN tablea ta ON ta.id = tb.id_a
WHERE ta.id IS NULL
```

Another option is to use a `NOT EXITS` condition with a correlated subquery:

```
DELETE FROM tableb tb
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tablea WHERE ta.id = tb.id_a
)
```